# How to create assocations in Sequelize migrations?

Tags: node.js, migration, sequelize.js

I am using migrations to create entities. Naturally, some have relations between them. Until now, by using `sync(true)`, I enjoyed the benefit of Sequelize implementing the relations for me at the database level.

How do I express new relations in a migration?

1. One-to-many: Should I be taking care of the foreign key columns?
2. Many-to-many: Should I be creating the intermediate table and setting foreign keys on each entity's table?

Or: Am I supposed to run the migration and then `sync(false)`?
What about relations that are no longer relevant?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I use migrations, i set sync:false.

And to set associations, my model ends up like so:

User.js:

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
    var User = sequelize.define("User", {
        "fname": {
            "type": DataTypes.STRING,
            "unique": false,
            "allowNull": false
        },
        "lname": {
            "type": DataTypes.STRING,
            "allowNull": false
        }
    }, {
        "tableName": "Users",
        "classMethods": {
            "associate": function (models) {
                Locale.hasMany(models.Permissions);
            }
        }
    });

    return User;
};
```

This will still create the table if it doesn't exist. However I recommend that creating a table is still part of a migration. Please note that in your migration to create a table to include the id, updatedAt, createdAt and PermissionId columns (for the example above)